# How to determine in R a count of how many indices appear within a given time period?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R where it looks like:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3)
times <-  c("2021-02-01", "2021-02-02", "2021-02-05","2021-02-01","2021-02-02", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-09")


dat <- data.frame(times=times, ID=ID)

> dat
       times ID
1 2021-02-01  1
2 2021-02-02  1
3 2021-02-05  1
4 2021-02-01  2
5 2021-02-02  2
6 2021-02-05  3
7 2021-02-09  3
```

I would like to sort this into a tally by date, such that for a given date, it counts how many users appeared on the date, and appeared again within a 2 day time interval. Since on `2021-02-01` ID 1 appears and reappears again on `2021-02-02`, ID 1 would be counted in. ID 2 is also counted in as it also appears on `2021-02-01` and appears again on `2021-02-02`. The resulting data frame would look like

```
> dat_result
       times counts
1 2021-02-01      2
2 2021-02-02      0
3 2021-02-05      0
4 2021-02-09      0
```

Is there a way to achieve this by `data.table` or `dplyr`? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` approach :

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(times1 = as.Date(times), 
         times = factor(times)) %>%
  arrange(ID, times1) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(lead(times1) - times1 == 1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  count(times, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(times = as.Date(times))

#  times          n
#  <date>     <int>
#1 2021-02-01     2
#2 2021-02-02     0
#3 2021-02-05     0
#4 2021-02-09     0
```

For each `ID` keep only those rows that have difference of 1 day between the dates and count number of such dates.